# How to re-render a particular field in template_preprocess_node or template_preprocess_field?

Tags: 6, theming

This is really really easy in Drupal 7: just use [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) or [field_view_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7). Choose the latter if you want to re-render a particular field value, or the former if you want to re-render the whole field (label and all values).

However, I couldn't figure out how to do this in Drupal 6. I resorted to implementing hook_nodeapi and changing the node content before it was rendered. This approach cannot be implemented from the theme, though, I'm looking for a theme solution.

Answer (score 1):

In `template_preprocess_node($vars)`, you can do:

```
$node=$vars['node'];
```

and then all the fields of the node are available to you, and a quick

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($node,true) . '</pre>');
```

will show them to you.  So if you had a text field called `field_description` you can access it via:

```
$node->field_description[0]['value'];
```

and you can then modify to your heart's content, eg:

```
$node->field_description[0]['value']='What I really wanted to say was....';
```

and then at the end:

```
$vars['node']=$node;
```

sets it on its way.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to prepare the field, change some parameters and pass it through drupal_render(). And anyway, changing $vars['node'] would probably be useless since node.tpl.php prints $vars['content'].

Comment: D'oh.  You're right.  But I've long stopped using $content in my node.tpl.php's for this and a whole other raft of reasons.  But, you can cp `content-field.tpl.php` out of cck's directory and then cp it again to `content-field-FIELDNAME.tpl.php` and modify that to redo that field, and that will make it into $content.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't re-render the field items. field.tpl.php is just the wrapper.

Comment: Why can't you change the `<?php print $item['view'] ?>` in there to whatever you need to render field how you want it rendered? You have `$item['value']` or `$item['nid']` etc so you have the raw information to work with to do whatever... or am I totally missing the point here?

Comment: that is precisely what i'm looking for. The $item['value'] is not a renderable array, though, it's just the raw value (or a filtered value). What I want is to build the renderable array (with its '#theme' and '#formatter' items).